# a device generates random numbers on the interval (0,1). 100 random numbers are generated. Find P(mean > 0.53)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have come to $\mu = 1$ and $\sigma = 1$, therefore $P(Z > -0.47) = 0.3192$.

But I'm not so confident with my $\mu$ and $\sigma$. Could anyone tell me if I'm doing it right? Thanks

Comment: are they uniformly random? If so, you'll find a different $\sigma$

Comment: Assuming the distribution is uniform and $\mu$ is supposed to be the mean, it is $0.5$, not $1$.  Your $\sigma$ is also wrong, as it must be $\le 0.5$ for any distribution in $(0,1)$

Comment: jameselmore-yes they are uniformly random. How would i get 0.5 for μ and σ?

Comment: Are you supposed to use the central limit theorem? This website (http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52066.html) explains how to calculate the standard deviation and mean of a uniform distribution in particular.